# "Transport Phenomena" (Bird, Stewart, Lightfoot) difference between edition 1 and 2

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, chemical-engineering

What is the difference between *Transport Phenomena* first edition (1979) and second edition (2002)?
Which one do you recommend to be bought, taking into account that I am a student and that the first one is cheaper?

Comment: The revision contains significant corrections and extra content. You can get used versions from [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0470115394/ref=sr_1_1_twi_har_1_olp?ie=UTF8&qid=1444988067&sr=8-1&keywords=transport+phenomena+bird) for $40.

Comment: What kind of extra content? Furthermore, I'm not an English native speaker (level B2) nor I have any knowledge of specialized English and in my country the 2nd edition is available only in English; do you think it wolud be too difficult to understand the contents?

Comment: Generally, updated books contain information about new developments and improvements since the previous date of publication & they can also omit information that is no longer relevant to the subject.

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/365/16

Comment: @GlenH7 I also was insecure about this question being on-topic. Thank you for opening the discussion on meta.

Comment: @Cybex You should be able to participate in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/the-skunk-works) since you have >= 10 reputation on another site in the SE network. If you're ever uncertain about whether something would be on-topic and you want to get some feedback before posting, or if you want to talk about completely off-topic stuff, chat can be a good place for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [Wiley](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470115394.html) page:

> About the Revised 2nd Edition: Since the appearance of the second
>   edition in 2002, the authors and numerous readers have found a number
>   of errors--some major and some minor. In the Revised 2nd Edition the
>   authors have endeavored to correct these errors. A new ISBN has been
>   assigned to the Revised 2nd Edition in order to more easily identify
>   the most correct version.

New content:

> - Revised to include more extensive reference to applications of material covered and the addition of appendices.
> - Expanded coverage of: transport properties in 2-phase systems, boundary-layer theory, heat/mass transfer coefficients, dimensional
>     analysis and scaling

Concerning your issues with the English language used, your comment exhibits a good grasp of the English language and I would argue that a good understanding of Calculus is much more valuable than being a native English speaker for reading this book. Besides, many canonical literature is written in English and it would be good to get some practice in reading and understanding such texts. Good luck!

Comment: *I would argue that a good understanding of Calculus is much more valuable than being a native English speaker for reading this book* - do you say this based on being familiar with the particular textbook itself, or is this an assumption you're making of any books that cover this subject matter?

Comment: @Air - My statement is based on extensive experience in the subject area of 'Transport Phenomena' including the book discussed here.